# Spotfire automation options for non-administrator developers?

Tags: triggers, scripting, automation, ironpython, spotfire

I have developed a Spotfire dashboard and would like to automate the following:

- Update tables from a csv-file shortly after a certain csv-file gets created outside of Spotfire.
- Save the dashboard after the update is over.

The problem is that at my company the dashboard still has internal status "in development" even though it is already in use. Therefore, I can rely only on what my Spotfire user can do: scripts. As far as I can tell, the native Spotfire automation routines are not available to me (please correct me if I'm wrong).

I tried the following IronPython script as a naive solution:

```
import time
while True:
    if csv_already_there():
        update_table()
        save_dashboard()
    time.sleep(3600)  # sleep for one hour
```

But the script crashes Spotfire.

Note: what I am looking for is probably a kludge but I'm okay with that since it's just a temporary solution.